# How to keep python library compatibility for compiled version?

Tags: python, opencv, pip

I am struggling to make a small python Opencv solution get working.

Basically, I have compiled an Opencv version 4.7 Cuda compatible in an Anaconda virtual env. It is working fine. GPU is recognized and it is running smoothly.

However, when I tried to install a second library like Ultralytics that has dependency of Opencv as well I got an issue.

Ultralytics pip installation did not find any reference for the compiled Opencv and installed the newest version it found like 4.8.1.

After that, the cv2 is no longer pointing to my compiled version but, it is to version 4.8.1 instead.

I tried uninstalling version 4.8.1 manually and reinstall the compiled version of cv2. But I could not. The folder cv2 under site-packages was entirely replaced.

Did anyone face any issue like this?

If someone could drive me on how to reinstall compiled Opencv library manually without recompiling it (takes 90 minutes every time).

I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: to spare yourself the building, just depend on cudawarped's prebuilt packages: https://github.com/cudawarped/opencv-python-cuda-wheels (the repo's commits don't contain anything special but the CI is customized for cuda builds) -- if other libs depend on "regular" opencv-python packages, you need to tell pip to not enforce that dependency

Comment: py -m pip install ultralytics It released today. The new version is 8.0.230